# How to declare an array data type in rails generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am aware of `t.text :tags, array: true, default: []` this syntax in migration to create an array of data type text.
Can I do the same in the rails generator itself?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this following as:

```
rails g scaffold Todo tags:array
```

And you can check `migrate file` which was generated:

```
class CreateTodos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :todos do |t|
      t.array :tags

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use array itself

```
rails g resource Todo  tags:array
```

Comment: So this will be an array which can hold anything like ruby array?

Comment: Yes, but only in postgress and other databases where array data type is supported , not in mysql

Comment: it doesn't work for me. it says array data type is not recognized